# Treat free in app purchase as already purchased from the start

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing an iOS app which allows in-app purchases.

The in-app purchases are basically different themes/characters for the app.

I offer the default for free (obviously), and some more paid themes.

I implemented the store UI as a table view.

Now this is the part I'm concerned about: I added a free in-app purchase entry for the default theme. My code can identify the free products when it gets the product list from Apple infrastructure, and I treat the free ones as if the user has already purchased them (UI is set as product was purchased, user can use the theme).

My question: is this behaviour is acceptable by apple reviewers or my app/in-app purchase will be rejected for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of adding the free in-app purchase? I don't know much about the review guidelines, but it sounds like the kind of thing they would reject your app for. It would probably be easier to detect the default kit in some way other than a free in-app purchase.

**EDIT:** An alternative would be to add the default theme to the list after the list is retrieved from IAP. You could create a class that holds all the same information, but can be constructed with either data from IAP or from the default theme data.

Comment: The purpose was to get this default free theme in one list with the other paid themes. It did suspect apple will have a problem with it, although it is free so I don't deprive any real money from them.

Comment: @user1909868 Where is the list? Is it one you created or is it part of IAP?

Comment: The list is returned to me by IAP infra. at them moment the free product is included in the list, and my UI presents it as purchased automatically. What I would like is to merge the real list with my dummy free product somehow.

Comment: @user1909868 Wouldn't it be simpler to get the list from IAP, add the default theme, then display that list?

Comment: I guess it will be simpler, I was under the impression it is not a good idea to create an SKproduct object myself. I will actually create a wrapper object maybe to hold skproduct data or dummy data for the free theme.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, and it's been approved by Apple for a long time now. However, for my "free" content there is no actual SKU in the Apple infrastructure. Rather than create a SKU with some 'dummy' price (since you can't make an in-app purchase any less than Tier 1), I just present the free option in the UI as a peer of the purchasable options.

I would worry that if you do have an actual SKU with a price, but you give away that SKU, Apple may reject your product out of concern that you are doing an end-run around Apple payment and depriving them of their percentage of the sale. It's also possible they may not reject your app the first time, but will reject some later version when a more thorough tester pokes around. (Yes, really. I have twice had apps rejected that had had the offending behavior through three or four approved versions. Consistency? What?)

Relevant references:

```
11. Purchasing and currencies

11.1
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
11.2
Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected
...
11.7
Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type
```

from [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how did you implement your solution exactly? Can I merge the product list apple returns to me with a dummy skproduct object i create on the app itself?

Comment: yes, that's similar to what I did. I don't make a dummy SKProduct object, just an object of a different type that appears in the same list. In my case I get a list of all potential products, free and paid, from my own web server, then query that list of products against the Apple store.

Comment: Well that's sounds like a proper solution! I will create a wrapper object and fill it with the details from the skproduct, or from my dummy object when needed. Simple enough! Thanks!